# Deploying a VM with managed identity using Terraform on Azure fails

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-managed-identity

I am currently working on deploying a VM on Azure using Terraform. The VM deployed correctly when using client_id, subscription_id, client_secret and tenant_id in the AzureRM provider block. However, I want to make use of managed identities so I don't have to expose the client_secret.

Things I tried:
For this, I followed this [guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/guides/managed_service_identity)

I included the azuread provider block, used the "use_msi = true" to indicate that managed identities should be used. Also included the azurerm_subscription block,azurerm_Client_config, as well as a resource definition. Then added the role assignment to the VM.

Code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azuread = {
      source = "hashicorp/azuread"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  //client_id       = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  //client_secret   = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  //subscription_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  tenant_id       = "TENANT_ID"
  //use_msi         = true
}

provider "azuread" {
  use_msi   = true
  tenant_id = "TENANT_ID"

}


#Resource group definition
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "myVMachineRG" {
  name     = "testnew-resources"
  location = "westus2"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "myVNet" {
  name                = "testnew-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.myVMachineRG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myVMachineRG.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "mySubnet" {
  name                 = "testnew-internal-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.myVMachineRG.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.myVNet.name
  #256 total IPs
  address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "myNIC" {
  name                = "testnew-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.myVMachineRG.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.myVMachineRG.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.mySubnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

#ADDED HERE:


data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

data "azurerm_client_config" "example" {
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "testnew-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.myVMachineRG.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.myVMachineRG.name
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.myNIC.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_F2"

  #Option to delete disks when Terraform destroy is performed. 
  #This is to ensure that we don't keep wasting balance
  delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "OSDISK"
    caching           = "Readwrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  #Just for testing purposes, would be better to use a KeyVault reference here instead.
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    admin_username = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    admin_password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }

  #Force password to authenticate
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

data "azurerm_role_definition" "contributor" {
  name = "Contributor"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  //name               = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.name
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  //role_definition_id = "${data.azurerm_subscription.current.id}${data.azurerm_role_definition.contributor.id}"
  //principal_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.identity[0].principal_id
  principal_id = data.azurerm_client_config.example.object_id
}
```

Error:

```
Error: building AzureRM Client: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
│
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"],
│   on main.tf line 9, in provider "azurerm":
│    9: provider "azurerm" {
```

I dont understand why it's still asking to use az login when I am trying to use Managed Identity for log-in.

Redacted the tenantID for security purposes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same requirement in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully.

***Need to provide name of the managed identity if you are authenticating via managed identities in terraform.***

*Add*  `msi_name` *under* `azuread` *provider*.

**Note**: *As you have given, make sure that managed identities should have enough permissions (contributor role) to authenticate and create resources otherwise deployment will fail.*

***main.tf***

```bash
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}
variable "subscription_id" {
  default = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
subscription_id = var.subscription_id
}
provider "azuread"{
features{}
use_msi = true
msi-name = "jahnaviidentity" //Give Name of the Managed identity 
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "main-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "main-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "<configurationname>"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "main-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"


  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "osdisk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "<computername>"
    admin_username = "<admin/username>"
    admin_password = "xxxxxx"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = false
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

***Output:***

`terraform init`:

[image]

`terraform plan`:

[image]

`terraform apply`:

[image]

***Deployed successfully in Azure Portal:***

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! This was super helpful! I ended up using Service Principal because my plan was to be able to authenticate Azure using the Managed identity but I was misunderstanding that this can't be done without first having the managed identity created.

Answer (score 0):

your provider block has usemsi commented out for azurerm (the one that's failing.)  Is that just a code transfer mistake to this question?  Would have put this in comments but my reputation is not high enough.

Looks like azurerm might also need the subscription id (unlike azuread)
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/managed_service_identity

The use_msi property should be in azurerm as well.  From the above link:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSzCV.png)

Also, just ot be sure, you've already configured the managed identity to use for this purpose, right?

Comment: I have that commented out in the AzureRM block because it is in the AzureAD block. I believe it's not supposed to be in the AzureRM block

Comment: I have also tried uncommenting the subscription_id part in the AzureRM block. It produces the same error

Comment: @tt1997 yeah the docs say you've gotta have use_msi in the azurerm provider block as well.  See attached screenshot or link above.

Comment: when I add the use_msi in the Azurerm provider block as well as the AzureAD provider block, the terraform apply command just gets stuck and doesn't return anything...

Comment: What do you mean by "configured the managed identity" to use for this purpose? My understanding was that the terraform script would create the managed identity in azure for me as well

Comment: See the section in the linked reference called "Configuring a VM to use a system-assigned managed identity."  You have to assign the subscriptionid as a scope and contributor role to the managed identity you are going to use before you can have terraform use the identity to authenticate. From the link: "
Setting the ARM_USE_MSI environment variable to true tells Terraform to use a managed identity. In addition to a properly-configured management identity, Terraform needs to know the subscription ID and tenant ID to identify the full context for the Azure provider."

Comment: IF you look at the code, I do have the SubscriptionID as a scope and contributor role as well assigned in the Terraform script.

What do I need to do in Azure portal?

Comment: You are trying to deploy azure VM with system assigned identity enabled as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/rRx9dra.png). Is my understanding correct? @tt1997